# PHP cURL to jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

I recently set up a firebase site which is the reason why I need to convert a PHP cURL request to a jquery client-side request. The code below is working for cURL, it is a posting to Paypal.

```
// Init cURL
$request = curl_init();

// Set request options
curl_setopt_array($request, array
(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
  CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array
    (
      'cmd' => '_notify-synch',
      'tx' => $tx,
      'at' => $your_pdt_identity_token,
    )),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE
));

// Execute request and get response and status code
$response = curl_exec($request);
$status   = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Close connection
curl_close($request);
```

As I am inexperienced with ajax I'm quite unsure how to start or if it's possible...

My question how to convert this cURL request to jquery ajax.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: What is your question or problem?

Comment: My question how to convert this cURL request to jquery ajax.

Comment: I don't think you would want to call PayPal with your credentials and signature from the openness of client side...

Comment: Yes I agree, I'm just looking for a temporary solution and for future reference though.

Comment: This is neither a code conversion site nor a tutorial site. You need to do this yourself, this includes doing research. Google has enough tutorials about making an AJAX request with jQuery. If you have any specific problem or question, you can come back.

Comment: @BernardoRodriguez Well, you're basically using curl to call a URL and send POST fields, so just google for "send post by ajax jquery" or something like that. Plenty of examples :) I think it would be better though to keep this on your server and make the ajax call to this script, in your server. This way you won't have to deal with sensitive information on the client side.

Comment: the paypal api isn't cors enabled. Why are you wanting to do this in the first place?

Comment: Yeah sorry as I researched more I realized that. The reason why is because I'm making a firebase application which only runs client-side... I guess I'll have to find another way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As charlietfl pointed out in the comments, Paypal isn't Cors enabled so this question is irrelevant. Sorry for wasting anyone's time...